# Is it possible to create a local repository that will clone GitHub's?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote, git-subtree

Let me explain,
Is it possible to create a local git directory(lets call it `my_github`) that will be the clone of:

> https://github.com/USER_NAME?tab=repositories

And then if i'll be interested in creating a new repository, i'll be able just to create a new folder in `my_github`, and just push it, and it will be pushed as a new repository.

And then my local directory will look like that:
`~/my_github/new_repo`
and when i'll push it, it will create `github.com/USER_NAME/new_repo`.

I tried to do that with `https://github.com/USER_NAME/USER_NAME` as my `remote origin` but it didn't work because it adds the files into the `USER_NAME/USER_NAME` repository, but I want it to add it to `/USER_NAME`.

I hope I was clear enough.

I just want to create repositories quickly and easier and push it to my github to the front page of my profile and not into some other repository.

The other way is to manually create a repository each time I want to create one through the web explorer, and link it to the local one. But I want to avoid this and want my `~/my_github/` directory to be synced with `github.com/USER_NAME`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. You are asking for `git`to do things specific to `GitHub`.

So I could propose you a workaround:

> I just want to create repositories quickly and easier and push it to my github

Perhaps have a look at the official GitHub cli:

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create

And you could still use `git`or shell alias to make the use suits your need:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Especially last paragraph.